# C# How to make all pages fit into Panel without adding horizontal scroll bar in cefSharp browser

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

In WinForms my Panel size is 560x371. Some pages fit into this size without adding horizontal scroll bar but some pages do not fit and horizontal scroll bar adds. How to make all pages fit (without exception) and without adding horizontal scroll bar?

For example:
google.com fit into Panel without adding horizontal scroll bar, but yahoo.com does not fit and adds horizontal scroll bar

Here is my code

```
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chrome;
        public CefSettings settings;
        string main_site = "https://yahoo.com";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitBrowser();
        }

public void InitBrowser()
        {
            settings = new CefSettings()
            {
                LogFile = "Debug.log", //You can customise this path
                LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Default // You can change the log level
            };
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            settings.CachePath = path;
            Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
            chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(main_site);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(chrome);
            chrome.MenuHandler = new DevToolsMenuHandler();
            chrome.AddressChanged += Chrome_AddressChanged;
            chrome.LifeSpanHandler = new MyCustomLifeSpanHandler();
       }
```

My new addintion (26.04.2022)

I also added code below

```
        private async void OnBrowserFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs args)
        {
            var client = chrome.GetDevToolsClient();
            await client.Emulation.SetDeviceMetricsOverrideAsync(500, 1000, 0, false);
        }

chrome.FrameLoadEnd += OnBrowserFrameLoadEnd;
```

You can see in the screenshot below, the code above trims the page.
But i need to fit all content into Panel without loss of content

[launch app result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y06qe.png)

Comment: You can't control how WebPage is rendered. It's something that depend of each page. If the page is designed as a responsive one, you never seen horizontal scrollbars. If you want work on a concrete page then, yes, you can use JavaScript to modifify styles or even the DOM of the page and adjust to your needs.

Comment: Another option is set the Anchor or Dock of your panel, allowing your browser may be resized, as a regular browsers.

Comment: You might be able to zoom the browser to achieve the desired behaviour though I expect you'd end up with web pages that were too small to use. I haven't tested, so pure speculation. Be something like get the content size, calculate zoom level, call SetZoomLevelAsync

Comment: Example of getting content size at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.OffScreen/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs#L655

Comment: amaitland, Sir i added new addintion please read above

Comment: Correction, call http://cefsharp.github.io/api/100.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_SetZoomLevel_1.htm I'd suggest trying say a value of 0.5 on a web page that doesn't fit. Unless a website implements a responsive design then it won't scale based on size.

Comment: amaitland, Sir if you recommended SetZoomLevel for checking is a website implements a responsive design or no. Answer is no. So is it impossible to solve this problem?

Comment: You can check the content size, if it's greater than your width/height then zoom the browser out. You may end up zooming out so far pages are difficult to read. You'll have to experiment to see if this meets your requirements.